# override laravel 5.7 autodiscovered package routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am having trouble allowing users to override my package routes. Because the package is auto discovered, I am unable to do the [usual fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723747/laravel-5-4-how-to-override-route-defined-in-a-package) for this.

The desired result is if in the routes->web.php a user defines route '/home', and in my package's routes.php file I also have '/home', the web.php version is used.

Let me know what other code I need to be looking at to solve this!

Package Service Provider:

```
no longer relevant
```

Solution:

To solve this issue in the manner I intended, (without breaking autodiscover) you will need to check for other routes within the route that generally overrides user routes. For instance, this function here which has the route '/{slug}' generally breaks a users web.php routes like '/userroute'.

My workaround goes like this.

```
public function page($slug){
    $route = $slug;
    $routes = Route::getRoutes();
    foreach($routes as $r){
      if($r->uri() == $route){
        $name = $r->getActionName();
        if(isset($name)){
          return \App::call('\\'.$name);
        }
      }
    }
    //add route code after
```

We need to call the route directly, to stop an endless redirect from occurring. This works well for me, because I can control which package routes a user is able to override in his web.php file, however I am sure there must be a faster way to achieve all this.

Comment: I have fixed this by creating a catch all route and looking for any other routes with matching names.

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with your workaround code please? I'm having the exact same problem. The best solution I have is to use the `dont-discover` feature and educate other developers to manually add my service provider AFTER `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`. Thanks.

Comment: Question updated! I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a **dont-discover** node to your composer.json file to exclude packages from auto discovery.

```
"extra": {
  "laravel": {
    "providers": [
      "WindfallInc\\Woodpecker\\WoodpeckerServiceProvider"
    ],
    "dont-discover": [
        "windfallinc/woodpecker"
    ]
  }
}
```

Taylor talked about this feature on Medium when he added auto discovery on Medium.
https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/package-auto-discovery-in-laravel-5-5-ea9e3ab20518

Comment: I am looking for a way to override though, without removing the 'plug and play' functionality that package discovery brings. If you set a don't discover, the user would be required to manually add the service provider. Which could lead to the exact same problem if the user puts it in the wrong place.

Comment: I think you as the package creator are not supposed to use `dont-discover`, but *the people installing your package* are supposed to use the `dont-discover` in the main `composer.json` of their project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219976/how-to-extend-vendor-package-service-provider-in-laravel-5-5#comment97087683_50220159